Despliegue de aplicacion de NextJS Error: TypeError: fetch failed
Buen día comunidad estoy intentando desplegar una sitio web que hice con NextJS y Supabase, el sitio web se desplega correctamente, pero cuando ingreso a el, obtengo este error:
{
  message: 'TypeError: fetch failed',
  details: 'TypeError: fetch failed\n' +
    'at n (/app/.next/server/chunks/3282.js:1:6583)'
    'at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)',
  hint: '',
  code: ''
}

Pero solo pasa con peticiones que se realizan desde el backend de NextJS, no se como solucionar.
Aqui dejo el Dockerfile que utilizo:
#Stage 1: deps
FROM node:18-alpine AS deps

ARG REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL
ARG REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY
ARG REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY
ARG REACT_APP_SITE_KEY
ARG SUPABASE_KEY_PAYMENTS
ARG BASE_URL_PAYMENTS

ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL=$REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY=$REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY
ENV REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY=$REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_SITE_KEY=$REACT_APP_SITE_KEY
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY_PAYMENTS=$SUPABASE_KEY_PAYMENTS
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL_PAYMENTS=$BASE_URL_PAYMENTS

RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --frozen-lockfile

ENV NEXT_PRIVATE_STANDALONE true

#Stage 2: Builder
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder

ARG REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL
ARG REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY
ARG REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY
ARG REACT_APP_SITE_KEY
ARG SUPABASE_KEY_PAYMENTS
ARG BASE_URL_PAYMENTS

ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL=$REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY=$REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY
ENV REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY=$REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_SITE_KEY=$REACT_APP_SITE_KEY
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY_PAYMENTS=$SUPABASE_KEY_PAYMENTS
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL_PAYMENTS=$BASE_URL_PAYMENTS


WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

#Stage 3: Runner
FROM node:18-alpine AS runner

ARG REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL
ARG REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY
ARG REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY
ARG REACT_APP_SITE_KEY
ARG SUPABASE_KEY_PAYMENTS
ARG BASE_URL_PAYMENTS

ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_URL=$REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY=$REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY
ENV REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY=$REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_REACT_APP_SITE_KEY=$REACT_APP_SITE_KEY
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_KEY_PAYMENTS=$SUPABASE_KEY_PAYMENTS
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL_PAYMENTS=$BASE_URL_PAYMENTS


WORKDIR /app

RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

# Files needed for configuration
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.mjs ./
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

# Files fot build Next
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

ENV PORT=3007
ENV HOSTNAME="0.0.0.0"
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "server.js"]

Las variable de entorno las paso como argumentos al Dockerfile no las pondre con los valores reales por seguridad
REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL=https://rfxx....supabase.co
REACT_APP_SUPABASE_KEY=eyJhbxxxxxxxx

Este es mi archivo next.config.mjs:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: "standalone",
  // Configuracion para la tunelización
  experimental: {
    serverActions: {
      allowedOrigins: ["c2df96k8-3000.usw3.devtunnels.ms", "localhost:3000"],
    },
  },
  images: {
    minimumCacheTTL: 60,
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "rfgspzjirszjxyddzfqy.supabase.co",
      },
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "ibvvnampnanunkozcgso.supabase.co",
      },
    ],
  },
  //Configuración de Proxy
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/api/:path*",
        destination: "http://localhost:8080/api/:path*",
      },
    ];
  },
};

export default nextConfig;

La verdad no se que me haga falta configurar, espero me puedan ayudar llevo varios días atorado aqui
